# Do I need Mac to develop Azure Xamarin.iOS application?

Tags: ios, macos, azure, xamarin

Regular Xamarin (not the Azure version) clearly requires Mac computer running Mac OS X to develop iOS applications. But in Microsoft Azure Xamarin.iOS documentation, there is no such prerequisite anywhere. Does it mean that I can develop iOS applications with Azure Xamarin.iOS on a Windows machine, without a Mac?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the Microsoft Azure Xamarin.iOS you found?

Comment: @CSharpRocks, Microsoft Azure Xamarin.iOS article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-xamarin-ios-get-started/

Comment: Oh I see where the confusion comes in.  This is an SDK that Microsoft offers to access the Mobile Services service. It is not an Azure specific version of Xamarin, it's just a library.  Igor an yairsz answers are correct, you do need a mac to compile your Xamarin.iOS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter which type of iOS application or libraries you want to use, you'll need a Mac to compile the project.

> Xamarin iOS for Visual Studio accomplishes an amazing feat: it lets
>   you create, build and debug iOS applications on a Windows computer
>   using the Visual Studio IDE. It cannot do this alone – iOS
>   applications cannot be created without Apple’s compiler, and they
>   cannot be deployed without Apple’s certificates and code-signing
>   tools. This means that your Xamarin.iOS for Visual Studio installation
>   requires a connection to a networked Mac OS X computer to perform
>   these tasks for you. Once configured, Xamarin’s tools will make the
>   process as seamless as possible.

ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of similar quiestion, you can develop on PC, but you need mac to compile the ios native code

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin offers a ready made component to work with Azure. You would include that in your iOS and/or Android application. To build for iOS you will still need to do it with a mac.So the answer to your question is no.